# Group by empty records

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have table with structure like this:

```
 --------------------------------------------
|  id  |  tid  | uid |   title   |   time    |
 --------------------------------------------
|  1   |   3   | 15  |           |   120333  |
 --------------------------------------------
|  2   |   3   | 15  | Lorem ip..|   120394  |
 --------------------------------------------
|  3   |   3   | 15  |           |   120344  |
 --------------------------------------------
|  4   |   2   | 15  | Lorem ip..|   128994  |
 --------------------------------------------
|  5   |   2   | 15  | Lorem ip..|   126782  |
 --------------------------------------------
```

And i have query like this (it selects all records with "uid" - user id that is 15):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE uid = :uid GROUP BY tid ORDER BY time DESC
```

Thos works fine, BUT u have one problem: "title" row is often empty when i display results of this query. (note: for every "tid" number there must be at least one "title")

How can i force this query to always display title, so it is never empty?

Comment: Are you looking to put in a default value if it is empty?

Comment: So to clarify, you want it so that if you to `GROUP BY`, the title it shows should not be blank? Which value should it use then? one of the non-blank ones, or a default value? (remember you are using `ORDER BY` time...)

Comment: What happens if all the titles are blank?  Can't you simply check `where title != ''`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you want to take an arbitrary value for the Title field, or if they are all the same, you could do a MIN() on that column.  MIN will omit nulls.

Comment: Something like: `SELECT id, tid, uid, MIN(title) AS title, time FROM my_table WHERE uid = :uid GROUP BY tid ORDER BY MIN(time) DESC`

Comment: Great, that was thing i was looking for, very simple, tnx man.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT COALESCE(title, 'no title'), * FROM my_table WHERE uid = :uid GROUP BY tid ORDER BY time DESC
```

Comment: This will just result in 'no title' instead of null, still not grabbing the one or two existing column values.  (also, * should be my_table.* when it's not the only thing after select)